# Closing <p> tags in badly formatted html with beautifulsoup 4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've got one not so valid set of html-pages to scrape. The data I need is in "p" tags. However, most of them aren't closed:

```
<p>Bla-bla-bla
<p>bla bla
<p>more bla-bla
<p><span class="some_class">another bla</span>
<p>just some more bla bla bla
<div class="another_class"></div>
<script>
<p>here's some more </p>
```

so when I perform a search, it gives me a messy resultSet of accumulated data:

```
In [2]: html='''
<p>Bla-bla-bla
<p>bla bla
<p>more bla-bla
<p><span class="some_class">another bla</span>
<p>just some more bla bla bla
<div class="another_class"></div>
<script>
<p>here's some more </p>'''

In [3]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

In [5]: p = soup.find_all('p')

In [6]: len(p)
Out[6]: 5

In [7]: p[0]
Out[7]: 
<p>Bla-bla-bla
<p>bla bla
<p>more bla-bla
<p><span class="some_class">another bla</span>
<p>just some more bla bla bla
<div class="another_class"></div>
<script></script></p></p></p></p></p>

In [8]: p[1]
Out[8]: 
<p>bla bla
<p>more bla-bla
<p><span class="some_class">another bla</span>
<p>just some more bla bla bla
<div class="another_class"></div>
<script></script></p></p></p></p>

In [9]: p[2]
Out[9]: 
<p>more bla-bla
<p><span class="some_class">another bla</span>
<p>just some more bla bla bla
<div class="another_class"></div>
<script></script></p></p></p>
```

I guess the default 'html.parser' just closes all tags at the end of the input string no matter what tags there are. In my case I would like a parser to parse tags not so greedy so that I could get a list of paragraphs at the end of the day. Is there any obvious solution or I should deal with this accumulated set and clean it by, for instance, subsequent substracting of strings or something?

(Also soup loses the last "p" - the only one that is formatted correctly, that's pretty weird.)

Comment: I don't think there is anything weird happening considering you have severely broken html

Comment: Completely agree. This question is about how best to clean up poorly written HTML.Most of the time this will involve an iterative process, getting you 80-95% of the way there and then cleaning up whatever is left.

Answer (score 2):

[From bs4 docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

> Another alternative is the pure-Python html5lib parser, which parses HTML the way a web browser does.

So:

```
pip install html5lib
```

And then

```
In [14]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

In [15]: p = soup.find_all('p')

In [17]: p[0]
Out[17]: <p>Bla-bla-bla\n</p>
```

The last paragraph is still lost, however:

```
In [18]: len(p)
Out[18]: 5

In [19]: p2
Out[19]: 
[<p>Bla-bla-bla\n</p>,
 <p>bla bla\n</p>,
 <p>more bla-bla\n</p>,
 <p><span class="some_class">another bla</span>\n</p>,
 <p>just some more bla bla bla\n</p>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
html.replace("<p>", "</p><p>")
```

And then:

```
html.replace("</p><p>", "<p>", 1)
```

to clean up the first tag.

Answer (score 0):

If every `p` tag has its own line, you could strip whitespace from the input text (to prevent a blank line at the end) and then try:

Search: `(?<!(div|script|p)>)$`

Replace: `</p>`

That will add a closing `p` tag to every line end, if the line doesn't end with a opening or closing `div`, `script`, or `p` tag. To exclude further tags (like `table` etc.), add them in the same manner:

`(?<!(div|script|p|table|tr|td|th|section)>)$`

etc.